Is the (inverse) Dold-Kan functor fully faithful on chain complexes of commutative monoids?
My question
The background/notation for all of the content of this post is in Lurie, Higher Algebra [HA], Ch. 1.2.3. Everything is purely 1-categorical.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ a semiadditive category (with biproducts and 0). Then there is a Dold-Kan functor
$$
\mathrm{DK}\colon\mathrm{Ch}_{\geq0}(\mathcal{A})\to\mathbf{s}\mathcal{A},
$$
where $\mathbf{s}\mathcal{A}=[\mathbf{\Delta}^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal{A}]$ and $\mathrm{Ch}_{\geq0}(\mathcal{A})$ is non-negatively graded chain complexes in objects of $\mathcal{A}$. Take $\mathcal{A}=\mathbf{CMon}$ the category of commutative monoids. My question is whether $\mathrm{DK}$ fully faithful in this case.
Brief background
The definition of the functor is in [HA, Construction 1.2.3.5]; it is defined as a composite $\mathrm{Ch}_{\geq0}(\mathcal{A})\to[\mathbf{\Delta}_{\mathrm{inj}}^{\mathrm{op}},\mathcal{A}]\to\mathbf{s}\mathcal{A}$ with the middle category being semisimplicial $\mathcal{A}$-objects. The first functor takes a chain complex $(A_*,\partial)$ to the semisimplicial object $[n]\mapsto A_n$ and on all non-identity order preserving injections it is zero except for $d^n$, which is sent to $\partial_n$. The second functor sends a semisimplicial object $A_\bullet$ to the sum
$$
[n]\mapsto\bigoplus_{\phi\colon[n]\twoheadrightarrow[k]}A_k
$$
indexed by surjections in $\mathbf{\Delta}$. On maps $[n]\to[n']$ it defined using the unique factorization into a split epi + mono - the details are in [HA, Construction 1.2.3.5].
If we take $\mathcal{A}=\mathbf{Ab}$, then $\mathrm{DK}$ is an equivalence by the Dold-Kan correspondence; more generally the same is true if $\mathcal{A}$ is any additive idempotent-complete category [HA, Thm. 1.2.3.7]. If $\mathcal{A}$ is only additive, then $\mathrm{DK}$ is only fully faithful. This can be easily deduced, as Lurie does, from standard Dold-Kan.
However, visibly $\mathrm{DK}$ makes sense for any semiadditive $\mathcal{A}$. I am interested in the case of $\mathbf{CMon}$ as posed in the question because I think that using a purely categorical argument this will show $\mathrm{DK}$ is fully faithful for any semiadditive category.
What I have so far...

$\mathrm{DK}$ is faithful. This is clear from the definition since for each $n$ we can recover $f_n$ from $\mathrm{DK}(f)_n$ via the biproduct maps.
If $g\colon\mathrm{DK}(A_*)\to\mathrm{DK}(B_*)$ is a simplicial map, using the argument in (1) we can recover the unique $f$ which we hope satisfies $\mathrm{DK}(f)=g$. Because $\mathrm{DK}$ is defined using the boundary map, I was able to show that this $f$ is indeed a chain map by writing out some diagrams.
I think, from this, it suffices to show that each $g_n\colon\mathrm{DK}(A)_n\to\mathrm{DK}(B)_n$ is given by a "diagonal matrix" in the sense of the defining direct sum.

As it stands, I don't have a strong guess as to whether this is true or not. Unfortunately the original Dold-Kan proof doesn't help since we cannot define a chain complex from a simplicial commutative monoid - the standard construction needs $-1$.
If this isn't true, a counterexample in $\mathbf{CMon}$ would of course be perfect, but by my earlier remark a counterexample for any semiadditive category would suffice (e.g. maybe there's some obvious reason chain complexes in some $\mathcal{A}$ can't embed into simplicial objects). But this would have to be a non-additive semiadditive category...
Any ideas are appreciated!
Edit$'$: Based on Chris's suggestion, let $$N_*\colon\mathbf{s}\mathbf{CMon}\to\mathrm{Ch}_{\geq0}(\mathbf{CMon})$$
be the corresponding functor. I (think I) can prove $N_*\circ\mathrm{DK}\cong\mathrm{Id}$ (see [HA, Remark 1.2.3.11]). I want to use this to deduce $\mathrm{DK}$ is fully faithful. It is clear if $N_*$ is faithful, but I'm not able to prove this without using $-1$. Another way to do it would be to show $N_*$ is right adjoint to $\mathrm{DK}$ as [HA, Lemma 1.2.3.12] does in the abelian category case. I'm having some trouble verifying the construction, though.

If I have a simplicial commutative monoid, $A_\bullet$, let $B_n$ be the intersection in $A_n$ of the kernels of all the $d_i$ except $d_n$, and let the differential be the last map $d_n$. Doesn't this define a chain complex $B_*$?

That is indeed a chain complex and functorial. It occurs to me that the original Dold-Kan defines this complex with differential $(-1)^{n}d_n$ only so that the natural map into the Moore complex is a chain map, which is needed for the other direction of equivalence. In any case, I think your functor $\widetilde{N}$ is indeed a left inverse to $\mathrm{DK}$ via the usual proof. In this case I hope you will post this as an answer.

@ChrisSchommer-Pries Update: I believe you are correct. Some confusion stemmed from different notation between Lurie and Goerss-Jardine. Regardless, your functor is a proper left inverse to what I've called $\mathrm{DK}$ and I will be happy if you post as an answer.

I don't understand your Edit 2 : CMon is certainly semiadditive, and the definition/verification of that fact does not involve the tensor product

Commutative monoids in a symmetric monoidal category have coproduct given by tensor product in the base category. In this case the base category is the category of sets with the cartesian product.

Ah, of course, thank you both for the clarification! In that case I believe the original logic stands, and Chris's suggestion answers my question allowing me to generalize full faithfulness to any semiadditive category.

@ChrisSchommer-Pries I agree that your construction gives a left inverse to $\mathrm{DK}$. To prove $\mathrm{DK}$ is full, I seem to need that your construction is a faithful functor. Is this obvious/true?

Chris’s functor obviously preserves limits (since it’s defined using kernels) (and the kernels are split so it also commutes with colimits) so it has a left adjoint and a right adjoint. Similarly for the dold kan functor. You should be able to compute the left adjoint on representables pretty easily to see it agrees with the dold kan functor. Then the isomorphism of composite functors you have is presumably the unit so it’s fully faithful (though iirc it’s not actually necessary to check this last bit)

@TimCampion Thanks, sorry can you specify the result you're using for "compute the left adjoint on representables pretty easily to see it agrees with the dold kan functor"? I tried to use the fact that every colimit-preserving functor out of a presheaf category has a right adjoint (determined by value on representables), but DK is the left adjoint. Or are you using that Ch(CMon) is embedded in a presheaf category...?

$Ch(CMon) = Psh_{CMon}(Ch)$ is a $CMon$-enriched presheaf category, where $Ch$ is the $CMon$-enriched category whose object set is $\mathbb N$, and $Hom(n,m) = \begin{cases} \mathbb N & m \in {n, n +1} \ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. Composition is defined in the unique possible way.

Thanks everyone, for completeness I'll outline the proof here. The answer is yes, over $\mathbf{CMon}$, $\mathrm{DK}$ is fully faithful. To check this we define $N_*$ in the opposite direction taking $A$ to the complex $NA_n=\bigcap_{i\geq1}\ker{d_i}$ with differential $d_0$.
Lemma $\mathrm{DK}$ is left adjoint to $N_*$.
Proof We can view $\mathrm{Ch}_{\geq0}(\mathbf{CMon})$ as a presheaf category enriched in $\mathbf{CMon}$ over the category $Ch$ described in Tim's latest comment. Now it is clear $\mathrm{DK}$ preserves colimits since we can check it pointwise and it was defined using coproducts. So $\mathrm{DK}$ has a right adjoint, say $R$; let the representables be $r_n$, then $R$ satisfies
$$
R(A)_n=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{sCMon}}(\mathrm{DK}(r_n),A)\quad\text{ in }\mathbf{CMon}
$$
The definition of how $\mathrm{DK}(-)$ on face maps shows that we can identify this hom-monoid with $NA_n$, thus $\mathrm{DK}\dashv N_*$.
Now the result follows from the observation that $N_*\circ\mathrm{DK}\cong\mathrm{Id}$. Indeed, that $A_n\subset N_n\mathrm{DK}(A)_n$ is easy to see, and the reverse inclusion follows from the fact that for any surjection $\phi\colon[n]\to[k]$, we can find $i\geq1$ such that $\phi\circ d^i$ is still surjective (then the condition on kernels implies only the $A_n$ submonoid remains) [HA, Remark 1.2.3.11]. We are done as such an isomorphism implies this is a fully faithful adjoint pair.

Have you looked at the same question in semi-abelian categories?  I know that there is
Dominique Bourn, Moore normalisation and Dold–Kan theorem for semi-Abelian categories, in Categories in algebra, geometry and mathematical physics , Contemp. Math. 431, 105–124, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI. (2007).  I am pretty sure that your question is not handled by this but the methods used may give you ideas on what you could try.

Thanks, for the nice reference. Unfortunately the main object of study in that paper is a functor back sA -> Ch(A), which a priori we don’t have here.
